# MVC4 Email verification websecurity token as querystring parameter, is it safe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, security, user-registration, email-verification

For security reasons I hate sites that use querystring parameters.

For my registration process, I'm sending a websecurity token via email to users who register. The user checks their emails and clicks on a link emailed to them to confirm who they are.

My issue is this, I don't wish to have a page on my site that accepts a query string parameter that could automatically log someone in, giving hackers a back door into other peoples accounts.

I have put a expiry date on the tokens, but I'd like to secure it further.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue if the token is single-use.  Anybody who tries to use the token after the intended user has already consumed it will see an error.  (Or you could just redirect straight to the login page.)

Comment: redirect to login is a clever idea